# How to rebind the "fn" key to mouse button 4

Tags: 18.04, xbindkeys

I want to rebind my FN key to my mouse button, but I'm having some issues. Currently using xbindkeys but have no idea how to configure it to what I need to do. Using **18.04**. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Fn key of a laptop typically is not seen by the OS. You cannot use it as a modifier key or assign it different functions.